# How to remove or update all React related dependencies/packages

Tags: reactjs

I have not worked with React for few years, but want to get back into it. The issue is that when i use basic command to setup new project

npx create-react-app new-app

i will get bunch of warnings like this and my project is completely missing stuff like public or src folder. So i am assuming things are quite broken:

```
warning react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin > native-url > querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > sockjs > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
warning react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
```

Is there some simple way to either remove all React related stuff from my system globally ( without reinstalling operating system ), so that i can install everything again or to update all of those automaticly? It seems like it would be best to just wipe all old stuff and just install everything again.

I have updated Node and tried to updated npx, but got this:

```
ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/npx/index.js
npm ERR! dest /Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/npx
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/npx/index.js' -> '/Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/npx'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/home/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/npx
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/home/.npm/_logs/2021-09-17T19_50_42_673Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try updating at least node and npx?

Comment: <https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies#uninstalling-global-packages> Check out the link above. Basically gives shortcuts for the terminal to uninstall various packages from the global environment.

Comment: @Sowam I updated comment based on your question. Did not fit there.